# No effect at applying of ON_CALL on a gmock object

Tags: dependency-injection, googlemock

For some fun purposes, I'm writing a Tetris game. I created two classes: "GameBackground" and "Tetromino". Since the "Tetromino" class has a dependency on the "GameBackground" class, I injected this dependency in the constructor using an interface such that I can test the "Tetromino" class independent of the GameBackground class by mocking it. When I use gmock to create the "GameBackgroundMock", the test fails. When I use my own mock like

```
    class MyOwnMock : public IGameBackground {
    public:
        MyOwnMock() : IGameBackground() {
        };
        bool RequestSpaceOnGrid(TetrominoPositionType requested_coordinates) override{
            return true;
        }
    };
```

then the test passes. Apparently, I don't use the gmock in the right way. I would appreciate any suggestion leading to a green test by using gmock.

For implementation details see the following code basis.

---

My initial folder structure looks as follows:

[Project structure][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h8zT.png

### **The corresponding files at the **project's top-level**:**

- **CMakeLists.txt.in**:

```
    # see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)
    
    project(googletest-download NONE)
    
    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(googletest
      GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
      GIT_TAG           master
      SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
      BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
      CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
      BUILD_COMMAND     ""
      INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
      TEST_COMMAND      ""
    )
```

- **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
    project(Test)
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    
    # Download and unpack googletest at configure time
    # (see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project)
    configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
    
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
            RESULT_VARIABLE result
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
    if(result)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
    endif()
    
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
            RESULT_VARIABLE result
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
    if(result)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
    endif()
    
    # Add googletest directly to our build. This defines the gtest and gtest_main targets.
    add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
            EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
    
    add_subdirectory(src)
    add_subdirectory(test)
```

### **The content of the **src folder**:**

- **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
    add_library(GameBackground_Lib STATIC GameBackground.cpp)
    add_library(Tetromino_Lib STATIC Tetromino.cpp)
```

- **IGameBackground.h**

```
    #ifndef TEST_IGAMEBACKGROUND_H
    #define TEST_IGAMEBACKGROUND_H
    
    #include <utility>
    #include <vector>
    
    #include <iostream>
    
    using TetrominoPositionType = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;
    
    class IGameBackground {
    public:
        virtual ~IGameBackground() = default;
    
        virtual bool RequestSpaceOnGrid(TetrominoPositionType) = 0;
    };
    
    #endif //TEST_IGAMEBACKGROUND_H
```

- **GameBackground.h**

```
    #ifndef TEST_GAMEBACKGROUND_H
    #define TEST_GAMEBACKGROUND_H
    
    #include "IGameBackground.h"
    #include <tuple>
    #include <utility>
    #include <vector>
    
    class GameBackground : public IGameBackground {
    public:
        GameBackground(int, int);
    
        bool RequestSpaceOnGrid(TetrominoPositionType) override;
    
    private:
        int m_horizontal_grid_size;
        int m_vertical_grid_size;
        int m_nr_buttomlines_filled{};
        std::vector<std::vector<bool>> m_occupancy_grid{};
    };
    
    #endif //TEST_GAMEBACKGROUND_H
```

- **GameBackground.cpp**

```
    #include "GameBackground.h"
    
    GameBackground::GameBackground(int vertical_grid_size, int horizontal_grid_size)
            : m_horizontal_grid_size{horizontal_grid_size},
              m_vertical_grid_size{vertical_grid_size} {
        m_occupancy_grid.resize(vertical_grid_size);
        for (auto &row : m_occupancy_grid) {
            row.resize(horizontal_grid_size);
        }
    }
    
    bool GameBackground::RequestSpaceOnGrid(
            TetrominoPositionType requested_coordinates) {
        bool is_every_coordinate_within_bounds{true};
        for (const auto &position : requested_coordinates) {
            int pos_x{position.first}, pos_y{position.second};
            if (pos_x < 0 || pos_x >= m_vertical_grid_size || pos_y < 0 ||
                pos_y >= m_horizontal_grid_size) {
                is_every_coordinate_within_bounds = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        bool is_request_successfull{false};
        if (is_every_coordinate_within_bounds) {
            try {
                bool is_occupied{false};
                for (const auto &position : requested_coordinates) {
                    int row{position.first}, column{position.second};
                    is_occupied |= m_occupancy_grid.at(row).at(column);
                }
    
                if (!is_occupied) {
                    for (const auto &position : requested_coordinates) {
                        int row{position.first}, column{position.second};
                        m_occupancy_grid.at(row).at(column) = true;
                    }
                    is_request_successfull = true;
                }
            } catch (std::out_of_range const &e) {
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
    
        return is_request_successfull;
    }
```

- **Tetromino.h**

```
    #ifndef TEST_TETROMINO_H
    #define TEST_TETROMINO_H
    
    #include <memory>
    #include <utility>
    #include <vector>
    #include "IGameBackground.h"
    
    
    enum class Direction { left, right, down };
    
    using TetrominoPositionType = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;
    
    class Tetromino {
    public:
        Tetromino(IGameBackground&, TetrominoPositionType);
        TetrominoPositionType getPosition();
        void setPosition(TetrominoPositionType);
        void moveOneStep(Direction);
    
    private:
        TetrominoPositionType m_position;
        IGameBackground& m_game_background;
    };
    
    #endif //TEST_TETROMINO_H
```

- **Tetromino.cpp**

```
    #include "Tetromino.h"
    
    #include <utility>
    
    Tetromino::Tetromino(IGameBackground &game_background,
                         TetrominoPositionType init_position)
            : m_game_background{game_background},
              m_position{std::move(init_position)} {};
    
    TetrominoPositionType Tetromino::getPosition() { return m_position; }
    
    void Tetromino::setPosition(TetrominoPositionType position) {
        m_position = std::move(position);
    }
    
    void Tetromino::moveOneStep(Direction direction) {
        TetrominoPositionType position = getPosition();
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction::down:
                for (auto &pos : position) {
                    ++pos.first;
                }
                if (m_game_background.RequestSpaceOnGrid(position)) {
                    setPosition(position);
                }
                break;
            case Direction::left:
                for (auto &pos : position) {
                    --pos.second;
                }
                if (m_game_background.RequestSpaceOnGrid(position)) {
                    setPosition(position);
                }
                break;
            case Direction::right:
                for (auto &pos : position) {
                    ++pos.second;
                }
                if (m_game_background.RequestSpaceOnGrid(position)) {
                    setPosition(position);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

### The content of the **test folder**

- **CMakeLists.txt**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
    add_executable(TetrominoTest TetrominoTest.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(TetrominoTest gmock_main gtest_main Tetromino_Lib)
```

- **TetrominoTest.cpp**

```
    #include "gmock/gmock.h"
    #include "gtest/gtest.h"
    
    #include "../src/IGameBackground.h"
    #include "../src/Tetromino.h"
    
    //class MyOwnMock : public IGameBackground {
    //public:
    //    MyOwnMock() : IGameBackground() {
    //    };
    //    bool RequestSpaceOnGrid(TetrominoPositionType requested_coordinates) override{
    //        return true;
    //    }
    //};
    
    class GameBackgroundMock : public IGameBackground {
    public:
        GameBackgroundMock() : IGameBackground() {
        };
        MOCK_METHOD(bool, RequestSpaceOnGrid,
                    (TetrominoPositionType requested_coordinates), (override));
    };
    
    class MoveTetromino : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        MoveTetromino() : unit_under_test(a_mock, init_position) {};
    
        TetrominoPositionType init_position{{0, 0},
                                            {0, 1},
                                            {0, 2},
                                            {0, 3}};
        Tetromino unit_under_test;
        GameBackgroundMock a_mock;
        //MyOwnMock a_mock;
    };
    
    TEST_F(MoveTetromino, move_right) {
        TetrominoPositionType current_position{init_position};
        TetrominoPositionType expected_position{init_position};
        for (auto &elem : expected_position) {
            elem.second++;
        }
    
        ON_CALL(a_mock, RequestSpaceOnGrid(current_position)).WillByDefault(::testing::Return(true));
    
        unit_under_test.moveOneStep(Direction::right);
        TetrominoPositionType actual_position = unit_under_test.getPosition();
        EXPECT_EQ(expected_position, actual_position);
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! One comment about your question: IMHO it contains too many details and code that is not relevant to the technical problem you are facing, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for details how to improve it. I know that it may be hard to tell what is relevant if you're not sure what is not working well, but the rule of thumb is that you should try to minimalize the amount of code you post to as small as it is possible and still showing issue in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test passes by calling either

`ON_CALL(a_mock, RequestSpaceOnGrid(expected_position)).WillByDefault(::testing::Return(true));`

or as Quarra suggested

`EXPECT_CALL(a_mock, RequestSpaceOnGrid(expected_position)).WillOnce(::testing::Return(true));`

The crucial point was to give **expected_position** instead of **current_position** to the mocked RequestSpaceOnGrid method.

Another possibility would be to get the test green to call the mocked method with `::testing::_`

`ON_CALL(a_mock, RequestSpaceOnGrid(::testing::_)).WillByDefault(::testing::Return(true));`

In this case, the mocked method would always return true independent of the given argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ON_CALL` which sets a default value to be returned when a mocked method is being called. This is useful if you don't care how many times given method will be called in your tests and you just set a default value to be returned any number of times (however, expect calls are being matched first, it's a longer story).

It's better to use `EXPECT_CALL` in your case to explicitly state what actions you anticipate and validate them:

```
EXPECT_CALL(a_mock, RequestSpaceOnGrid(current_position)).WillOnce(::testing::Return(true));
```

If you will use this, gmock will let you know what's wrong with the test: the `RequestSpaceOnGrid` was called, however not with `current_position` but with `expected_position`. Not sure if this is expected, but this is what happens in the test.

Comment: Hi Quarra, thanks for your answer, as you already noticed in your last paragraph, the fault was to call the mocked method with ```expected_position``` instead with ```current_position```.